# jQuery: disable class except current element

Tags: jquery, disabled-input, input-field

I have a table with several fields that act like filters. 
All fields have the same class and are empty by default.

Is there a way that I can only allow one of these fields at a time to be active and disable all others at the same time ?
What I want to achieve is that you can only fill in one field at a time, i.e. if you fill in one field then the others get disabled and when you empty this field again the others get reactivated.

My thought was to add a temporary class while entering data but I couldn't get this to work.

**My fields all look like this:**

```
<input type="text" class="inputFilter" id="input1" name="input1" value="" />
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $inputs = $('.inputFilter').on('input blur', function () {
        var value = $.trim(this.value);
        $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled', value.length != 0);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x6nGX/)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$('.inputFilter').change(function(){      
       if($(this).val() == "")
       {
            $('.inputFilter').removeProp('disabled');
       }
      else
       {
            $('.inputFilter').not($(this)).prop('disabled',true); 
       }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x6nGX/2/)

Comment: Thanks, this is great too - Arun's solution just seems to work better in my case.

Comment: @user2571510 Arun always better. :)

Answer (score 0):

you may use jQuery .each() in a way that will suit your needs:

for HTML:

```
 <input type="text" class="inputFilter" id="input1" name="input1" value="A" />
 <input type="text" class="inputFilter" id="input2" name="input2" value="B" />
 <input type="text" class="inputFilter" id="input3" name="input3" value="C" />
```

tweak the function for your needs:

```
function disableAllButX(x){
    $.each( $('input[type=text]') , function( i, element ){
        if(i!=x){
          element.disabled=true;
        } else {
          element.disabled=false;
        }
    });
}
```

and call it via some trigger (i.e onclick or onchange):

```
disableAllButX(1);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F99F8/)